# Maximum requests that a server can handle in parallel

Tags: testing, load, amazon-ec2

I am new to the web development. I am trying to implement web-services. I am using Amazon EC2 for storage.

The server that I am using should be able to handle 'n' number of requests per second in parallel. Because 'n' different clients can try to use my web-service at the same time from different devices.

How do I know the maximum number of requests that my Server can handle? I need to upgrade the server if it cannot handle the requirement. How Load UI tool will help me in finding this?

Comment: depends on number of parallel connectiosn?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that ***it depends*** on how your web-server works and how equal your clients are and what computation and bandwidth your clients require.

You really have to deploy a test system and benchmark several times at different points in the day (as your performance is affected by other customers demand) to understand the performance characteristics of your web-server and client profile.

I have previously [given anecdotal data-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648849/does-ec2-have-good-latency/1648857#1648857) about latency, but hesitate to say that I'm sure they are still true.  Only doing your own profiling with your own planned deployment will give you numbers you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know max performance try next steps.
1. Mark requirments to server as 100% load profile.
2. Test server by 10-20% (usually it's needed for debuging of test tool and scenarios)
3. Test by 100% profile.
4. If server is yet alive test by 200-300%.
6. Take very long test by 100% profile to check stability.

For all test (besides stability test) use ramp-up period about 20-60 minutes, and test time about 1-2 hours.